# Choose Which Albums Show in Play Music?

Tags: google-play-music

Not sure if this is a common or simple solution, but I can't find a way to fix this.

I've got a couple albums I've purchased through the Google Music store - namely the Lés Mis soundtrack, is it's a great musical and all that.

However, it's showing up on my phone, and I don't particularly *want* it on my phone.
If I shuffle my music, it keeps turning up.
If I make an instant playlist, it likes to show up. (Because apparently Lés Mis is very similar to Rust in Peace...)

I could set it to only steam via Wi-Fi, but then I need to keep the *rest* of my music on the device. And besides, as soon as I get on the Wi-Fi, it'll start streaming again..

How do I stop this album from showing up? I'd rather not *delete* it from Google Music Manager as that'll delete it from my account (I think). I just don't want it to ever show up on my phone.